# How to increase size of an object in an image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, geometry

I have a boundary shown in yellow, I want to draw another bigger one (shown in red) on the same image, any idea? Also, I have the object, I want to extend all corners of the object in the image by 20 pixels.

I want to do it in Python, `cv2.rezise()` will increase the size of the entire image, I just want to increase the size of the object or boundary area.

[image: sample image]

Comment: Are you asking about [vector of raster](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vector-vs-raster-graphics/) style resizing? Please post the original image, add a language tag, and add some source code (like using `cv2.resize` in Python).

Comment: @Rotem thanks for the reply, it has been updated.

Comment: I can't see your source code, and I can't see the original image. Please explain why resizing the entire image and then cropping the relevant area is not good enough.

Comment: @AbbasKhan "*I just want to increase the size of the object or boundary area.*", you can **mask** that area, **resize** that area, and then project it back to the original image.

Comment: resizing is absolutely the wrong operation. -- apply a `cv.dilate` with circular kernel. -- this operation, if applied to vector data, is called "offset". OpenCV does not do vector graphics.

Comment: Always best to post an original unmodified image so that others can test ideas on your data. Also properly you should show your code attempts for this forum. Get the outer contour of the yellow curve (after thresholding as white curve on black). Then draw it as a filled white contour on black background. Then use morphology dilation (as suggested by @Christoph Rackwitz). Then get the outer contour of that and draw it on your input image or on a purple background as desired.

Comment: Morphological operation : dilation is what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, cv.dilate and cv2.errosion   worked for my case.